# Excel vba dictionary loop stops responding

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

```
' Find the last row in both sheets
dictwslr = dictws.Cells(dictws.Rows.Count, dictkey_Col).End(xlUp).Row


' Populate branch dictionary from dictsheet. Add Multiple Columns if necessary using pipe separator
'Add pipe separated values for every column to be stored in the dictionary
Dim dictkeys As Variant
Dim dictValues As Variant
dictkeys = dictws.Range(dictkey_Col & dictstartrow & ":" & dictkey_Col & dictwslr).Value
dictValues = dictws.Range(dictvalue_col1 & dictstartrow & ":" & dictvalue_col1 & dictwslr).Value
For i = 1 To UBound(dictkeys, 1)
Dict.Item(dictkeys(i, 1)) = dictValues(i, 1)
Next i
```

I am trying to build a scripting dictionary with the above code. The dictwslr has a value of 208731, The dictstartrow has a value of 2. After reading the ranges into arrays, the code loops through the arrays and builds the dictionary. The loop keeps running for ever and Excel stops responding. What could be the issue and what is the fix?

Comment: For large loops like that, you can use something like `If i mod 1000 = 0 Then Debug.Print i`. As for the loop, adding to a dictionary usually goes like `If Not Dict.Exists(dictkeys(i,1)) Then Dict.Add dictkeys(i,1), dictValues(i,1)`. Give that a try and see if it helps.

Comment: @Notus_Panda, The Debug.print i ran till 25000 and then stopped. The loop has stopped responding. The keys are numerical digits of length 14. Is that in anyway contributing to the issue?

Comment: It shouldn't, just tested with lengths varying from 2 to 20, went through the loop in a few seconds and then pasted the `Dict.Keys` next to my ranges just fine. How much memory are you using before you reach that for-loop? Also, "stopped responding" is a very easily seen as such while it could just mean "taking longer than expected" with Excel though that shouldn't happen here since I tested 400k+ rows just now..

Comment: @Notus_Panda The loop ran at full speed once I converted the key to a string using CStr ie. Dict.Add CStr(dictkeys(i, 1))

Comment: Very interesting, I had mostly text in my keys due to how my company has their article codes set up. Converted most extensions to numbers, changed 0's to 7's so I wouldn't lose any leading 0's and thus not shorten their length and it came to a crawl around the 49k mark after already seeing a big increase in processing-time over the first 49k iterations. I wonder if it has something to do with the [CompareMode property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/comparemode-property) where it's easier comparing text than numbers?

Answer (score 0):

In this instance, the issue was resolved by converting the dictionary key to a string using VBA CStr function. The cause could be that the values of the key are 14 numerical characters and may be the cause of the slow processing unless converted to Strings.